# Python error with reading and writing

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv 
dataList = []

with open('N004_timetable.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        dataList.append[row]

csvfile.close()

print(dataList[2][2])
```

When I run this code I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\attendance\Class.py", line 5, in <module>
    for row in csvreader:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

I have tried doing

```
with open('N004_timetable.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
```

and I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\attendance\Class.py", line 6, in <module>
    dataList.append[row]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: "did you open the file in text mode": `with open('N004_timetable.csv', 'rb') as csvfile` => `with open('N004_timetable.csv', 'r') as csvfile`

Comment: as for `append[row]` typo => `append(row)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you :D

Comment: Small detail: You don't need to explicitly close the file (`csvfile.close()`) when using the context manager to open it (`with...`). It handles that for you.

Comment: You seem to be using Python 2 code in Python 3. Make sure to look at the right piece of documentation - in Python 3, you need to set the `newline` parameter when opening a CSV file, for example).